# Difference between omake and nmake

Tags: msbuild, build-process, visual-c++, nmake, omake

Please tell me the difference between omake and nmake. We want to migrate from omake to nmake as we are rolling out clearcase. Please explain the process of migration from omake to nmake? Also please let me know if there are some complications.

Comment: Not sure what kind of applications you are building. If it is Visual C++ based, please notice that Microsoft migrates to MSBuild in Visual C++ 2010,

http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2010/01/11/vcbuild-vs-c-msbuild-on-the-command-line.aspx

Comment: Hi Lex,

Thanks. it is Visual C++ based.

Comment: What omake are you talking about?  The one I'm familiar with is [the OCaml-based build system](http://omake.metaprl.org/manual/omake.html), but given the context of migration to nmake I'm not sure if that's the one you're using or if there's another "omake" tool that you're trying to migrate from.

Answer (score 0):

"**Omake** is the ClearCase® build utility"
"also features emulation modes, which enable you to use omake with makefiles that were constructed for use with other popular make variants, including Microsoft® **NMAKE**"

https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/omake.htm